# ASP.Net User Control Property

Tags: c#, asp.net

Note: This isn't homework, I've already graduated Comp Sci and this is for my own personal interest. I'm also using a textbook as my guide.

I'm currently in the process of learning ASP.Net 4.0 with C#, I've made solid ground but I'm getting an error that I can't figure out what the problem is.

I'm in the process of adding a viewState property to a part of my user control but the property isn't visible to the control I want to assign it to. Here is my viewstate:

```
public string NavigateURL
{
    get
    {
        object _navigateURL = ViewState["NavigateURL"];
        if (_navigateURL != null)
        {
            return (string)_navigateURL;
        }
        else
        {
            return "http://reddit.com";
        }
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["NavigateURL"] = value;
    }
}
```

and here is where I call it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Banner2.NavigateURL = "http://bbc.co.uk";
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error saying that banner doesnt contain a definition of NavigateURL despite the fact I have managed to use different properties from the same location before. I've combed the textbook and I've followed every instruction to the letter yet there is no mention of this error even being possible
Thanks for your time and effort

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: So the shown NavigateURL property is implemented on the control Banner2? And is the page_load also located on Banner2?

Comment: Post complete code here

Comment: As others have said, we really need to see the markup and code for both the control and the page you're using it on. However, assuming that the first code sample is from the control, the second is from the page, that the page actually has an instance of the control on it, and that the ID of the control on the page is Banner2, then I'd question whether or not the page's designer file has added the user control with the correct type. I've seen it happen where a user control added to a page gets typed in the designer as a generic user control. Changing it to the correct type may fix the problem.

Comment: Probably silly of me to mention, but when you add a new property to a user control, you usually need to rebuild the project before it's visible and usable to other code.

Comment: One thing I didn't see in my book is that I needed a fresh browser window. At first I ignored this because I didn't think it meant anything but eventually I closed the browser anyway. When I did this the error went away and the webpage displayed as I expected it to.

edit: This revelation coincides quite closely with what Nikki9696 has posted.
Im currently in the process in working out why this happened but its quite difficult to search for.